# What sleep charting software exists for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, software-recommendation

I'm looking for Mac software that will make it easier to generate a chart of my personal sleeping habits. I have a system improvised with Numbers '09, but it doesn't work very well. Is there any software out there that will do this simply? I want to log my sleep/wake times and have the chart generated for a given span of time easily. (If it can project times into the future, that's even better.)

Comment: What about your Numbers solution doesn't work well?

Comment: I can't get the scatter plot to distinguish between sleep and wake times, or to draw 'lines' of sleep time, so it's very confusing to look at. It's also very tedious to input the times, because Numbers seems to be very picky about how dates are inputted.

Answer (score 1):

I have this one here, very happy with it.

http://www.fitbit.com/

The last I checked, you can sign up for a fitbit account and use their web application to manually enter sleep times and get nice graphs and statistics using your web browser to see the data.

I don't think there is an export function and it's clearly not a traditional app where all the data exists on your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

[Zeo Mobile](http://www.myzeo.com/sleep/shop/zeo-sleep-manager-mobile.html) Everything you could ask for. 99$  it works.

Comment: This looks it's on the money, but I don't have a mobile device it would work with.

Comment: There is also a standalone version, bit more expensive, but beefier. You do not need a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have many options.

I just personally bought the Zeo. The Zeo has two options:

1. One that only connects to the bedside alarm (you can view data on the device, online, and with an iPhone app)
2. The second, only connects to iPhone and automatically uploads your data to the website.

I chose the bedside one because it got better reviews, it seems that they haven't gotten the iPhone version stable yet.

As mentioned before the Fitbit and a few others in the same class like Up, [Wakemate](http://wakemate.com/tour/) and basis. All of these use actigraphy except for Zeo which senses electric signals from the brain and face.

Both methods are accurate and are the same technologies that are used in sleep studies.

If you want a cheap way to get started try one of the iPhone apps that track your sleep from the movement of your mattress, like [Sleep Cycle](http://www.sleepcycle.com/)

Comment: Since this question is looking for Mac software, please be sure to edit your answer to explain how these iOS software and other packaged work or do not work on Mac OS X.